# Model multiple instances of hardware with UML

Tags: deployment, uml

Imagine that we have a simple structure of a client machine and a sever which are connected through the Internet. It is well-known how to show such structure with a deployment diagram.

Now I want to show that it is possible to have unlimited number of such clients and servers where each client **has a possibility** to be connected to each server. Moreover I want to show that each client machine has the same software client on it and each server has the same database scheme, but with one of different implementations (MySQL, Oracle, ...).

What the best and detailed way of model this with UML?

Comment: this http://www.uml-diagrams.org/web-application-load-balancing-uml-deployment-diagram-example.html is an example of deployment diagram with multiplicities. This http://www.uml-diagrams.org/network-architecture-diagrams.html example of network diagram (not UML) may also guide you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw deployment diagram as depicted on picture below.
Communication path between nodes defines that many clients and many servers communicate with each other. (top part of diagram)
There are instances of nodes from top part of diagram to define that there are concrete instances of database server on your server machines. Internet is not node of deployment from this point of view. Internet is form of communication realization between nodes.

If it is needed to define deployed code on nodes, use artifacts.
See, the database server is node as well, but of execution environment type !

here is my diagram. I hope it will help you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use **instances** of Components and Nodes:

[image]

The fact that each client can connect to any server could be shown as a simple note (pragmatic approach) or in some other diagram - collaboration for example (formal approach). If there is a dispatching algorithm in between, I sugest tha latter. If not, the note will be enough, as this is somehow expected.

I suggest to use a plain deployment diagram to show the dependencies